# HTML DIV layout requested

Tags: css, html

How can I obtain this structure with HTML `div`'s?

[image]

- The first `div` on the left is called: `idphoto`
- The upper right `div`: `idupper`
- The bottom right `div`: `idbottom`

Comment: Questions asking others to do all the work are frowned upon.  Plus the question is very vaugue, are these `div`'s a fixed width/height, dynamic, fluid, etc.

Comment: example: http://jsfiddle.net/7qLkb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS for positioning.

### HTML structure

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="contentLeft">
        <div id="idphoto"> ... </div>
    </div>

    <div id="contentRight">
        <div id="idupper"> ... </div>
        <div id="idbottom"> ... </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#contentLeft {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#contentRight {
    width: 69%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#contentRight #idbottom {
    /* Add additional height and width or positioning */
}

#contentRight #idbottom {
    /* Add additional height and width or positioning */
}
```

### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/Hnh8R/

Comment: this is the problem....how cani set css?

Comment: @michele I added a sample at JS fiddle with background colors for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="idphoto"> ... </div>

    <div id="contentRight">
        <div id="idupper"> ... </div>
        <div id="idbottom"> ... </div>
    </div>
    <div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container { height: 500px; width: 100%; }
#idphoto { float: left; width: 250px; height: 100%; }
#contentRight { height: 100%; }
#idupper { height: 75%; }
#idbottom { height: 25%; }
div.clear { clear: both; } /* this does something like make floated elements push whatever is below this */
```

Sample:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FTEd/1/)